# how to simulate firwalls and proxies when developing code?

Tags: java, proxy, firewall, mcafee

I am writing code that often has to work in restricted environment. I sometimes code at home, where it works nicely and the moment I put it to test at work, McAfee or some other firewall blocks it.
Sometimes it is not possible to disable such protection.

I need a test suite for my home development environment where I can simulate all these restrictions without having to install all of them myself (for instance it is my experience that it is very hard/impossible to clean all traces of mcafee once you have installed it). I also need to simulate proxy servers.

I am writing code in Java if it helps.

[EDIT: so some Java library for this would be great]

Comment: It might not be relevant but if you're finding yourself restricted at work, why don't try to lift that restriction somehow to make your job easier? For instance, if your firewall is not allowing you to make certain connections, you could speak to your system administrator and ask him to make an exception for you. If that is no option, I suppose a virtual development environment could do.

Comment: You can just kill your server/client in the middle of conversation and see what happens. Regarding proxies, why not just install proxy on your computer and configure your apps to work through it?

Comment: @Kevin. Actually the work environment is a "real world environment", where the app is actually deployed, and changing it is not possible due to "security reasons". A virtual dev environment is what I am currently using but it is a bit of hassle to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use VMware (or VirtualBox) with different test-setups.

Comment: Actually that is what I am currently doing.. I was hoping there is some library for this that I can use in Java.

Answer (score -1):

Try [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Also have a look at a [sample proxy implementation](http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/)